# JSON with symbols and strings not readable

Tags: ruby, json

I have the following JSON:

```
{ :a => 1, "b" => "test" }
```

`jsonObject[:b]` does not give me any data, whereas for a JSON with all keys as strings,

```
{ "a" => 1, "b" => "test" }
```

it works fine:

```
jsonObject[:b] # => "test"
```

Is there a constraint against using a symbol and key in the same JSON object?

Comment: What is `jsonObject`? What is `test`? Is it a variable or a method?

Comment: jsonObject has all the data. And test is just string data

Comment: For me both of them return `nil`. May you tell us what's the ruby class of those objects? Is it a Hash?

Comment: Question is not clear. Is `jsonObject` the string that has the JSON data? Then the method `[]` on a string cannot take a symbol `:b` as an argument. If, otherwise, `jsonObject` is a Ruby object converted from JSON, then whatever you do to it afterwards has nothing to do with JSON.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to parse a JSON to a Hash before using, like

```
require 'json'
JSON.parse("{...}")
```

and convert a hash to a JSON string by

```
hash.to_json
```

all keys of symbols and strings are converted into strings.

```
require 'json'
a = {:a => '12', 'b' => '23'}
p aa = a.to_json #=> "{\"a\":\"12\",\"b\":\"23\"}"
p JSON.parse(aa) #=> {"a"=>"12", "b"=>"23"}
```

Answer (score 0):

It might be possible that you are sometimes dealing with a simple `Hash` and sometimes with a [`HashWithIndifferentAccess`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/HashWithIndifferentAccess.html). The Rails' `params` for example allow indifferent access by default. This might explain your confusion:

```
hash = { :a => 1, 'b' => 2 }

hash[:a]
#=> 1
hash['b']
#=> 2
hash[:b]
#=> nil
```

But with a `HashWithIndifferentAccess`:

```
hash = hash.with_indifferent_access

hash[:a]
#=> 1
hash['b']
#=> 2
hash[:b]
#=> 2
```